# How to render a Log / text file in node js through url?

Tags: node.js, routes, render

I am trying to view the log File in the browser on hitting a particular url. I have the log file in my local (/logsFolder/app.log)

I tried the following codes:
**Code: 1**

```
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var logFile = require('/logs/app');
app.use('/logs',logFile);
```

It threw error like

```
Error: Cannot find module '/logs/app'
```

**Code :2**

```
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

 router.get('/logFile', function(req, res){
    console.log("inside logt :");
    res.render('./logs/app.log');
});
```

can anyone Please help me to resolve.

Answer (score 4):

Your log is static text file, not a javascript, nor json file, that why you can't require it. (code 1)

You are not using [template engine](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) either, that's why your code 2 didn't work, It cannot be render by itself.

You can use the built in `express` middleware for static files.

Try this:

```
app.use(express.static('logsFolder'))
```

Now you can access all the content of `logsFolder` by requesting the file name. For example: http://your-url/app.log

Or try your code 2 with `res.sendFile` instead of `res.render`

Comment: Thank you for your reply @yeya. It is not working.I used the code like the below.

var app = express();
var path = require('path');                                      app.use(express.static('logs/app.log'));

Comment: Looks at the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) or read my answer again. it should be express.static(<root folder>), not the file itself.